# Python Discord Bot: Use of "async" not allowed outside of async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, bots

I am making a discord bot in python, and some of the commands have the bot typing a bunch of nonsense. But I have to have the whole async with, asyncio.sleep everytime.

```py
@client.command()
async def talk(ctx):
            s(3)
            async with ctx.typing():
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
                await ctx.send("Hello")
            s(2)
            async with ctx.typing():
                await asyncio.sleep(4)
                await ctx.send("My name is bob.")
            s(5)
            async with ctx.typing():
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
                await ctx.send("But first..")
            s(2)
            async with ctx.typing():
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
                await ctx.send("Tell me more about astronomy.")
            s(2)
            async with ctx.typing():
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                await ctx.send("And about oranges.")
            s(2)
            async with ctx.typing():
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
                await ctx.send("Please")
```

I would like to put in a seperate method that I can call. Something like this:

```py
def speak(ctx, msg, prewait=0, typewait=3):
    sleep(prewait)
    async with ctx.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(typewait)
        await ctx.send(msg)
    return None
```

But this doesn't work as I cannot use the keyword async and await outside of async method.
Is there a clean workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

add `async` to your `def speak(ctx, msg, prewait=0, typewait=3)`.